# Number of filter coefficients and sampling rate in designing IIR filter

Tags: c++, filtering, signal-processing, digital-filter

Now I forgot all those filtering concept learned long ago.

Currently I am designing an IIR filter.
The filter works well if I set sampling rate to 50 samples/sec. Once I increased to 100 samples/sec, the filter output signal is distorted.
What could be the problem? I redesigned with increasing number of filter coefficients to double. But it is worse.

I implemented `IIR Direct Form 2 transposed filtration` as follow.

```
public void IIRDirectForm2TransposedFilteration(float x, float y, float z){

        out[0] = registerx[0] + Bcoefs[0] * x;
        out[1] = registery[0] + Bcoefs[0] * y;
        out[2] = registerz[0] + Bcoefs[0] * z;
        for(int i = 0; i < numcoefs-2; i++){
            registerx[i] = registerx[i+1] + Bcoefs[i+1] * x - Acoefs[i+1] * out[0];
            registery[i] = registery[i+1] + Bcoefs[i+1] * y - Acoefs[i+1] * out[1];
            registerz[i] = registerz[i+1] + Bcoefs[i+1] * z - Acoefs[i+1] * out[2];
        }
        registerx[numcoefs-2] = Bcoefs[numcoefs-1] * x - Acoefs[numcoefs-1] * out[0];
        registery[numcoefs-2] = Bcoefs[numcoefs-1] * y - Acoefs[numcoefs-1] * out[1];
        registerz[numcoefs-2] = Bcoefs[numcoefs-1] * z - Acoefs[numcoefs-1] * out[2];

}
```

Comment: Your filter design (i.e. filter coefficients) was probably done for the 50 samples/sec. When using it with 100 samples/sec your cutoff frequencies change. Btw this looks like C++ code rather than Matlab code...

Comment: What does "distorted" mean?

Comment: Have a look at Matlab's [`freqz` function](http://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) using your `Acoefs` and `Bcoefs`. You may also want to look for "normalized frequencies". ;)

Comment: @MatthiasW. Yes C++, but I designed in Matlab. Cutoff frequency is wider, right? Since mine is band pass, the distortion should be from the lower cutoff frequency.

Comment: If it is a lowpass filter I would say you have a wider passband, yes. Why? Because your normalized frequency will stay the same, but fs/2 is greater than before. But `freqz` also can take a sampling frequency as input. Edit: btw your question would probably fit better here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MatthiasW. Yes I designed my lower cutoff to 0.05 at 50 Hz and now I set it lower to 0.025 at 100 Hz. Then it is fine. Thanks

Comment: @batuman: Good to hear. Problem solved?